# Magento MAGMI - Custom Options not working correctly

Tags: import, magento-1.9, magmi

I'm trying to create custom options through magmi.

This is what I'm using

```
Choose your Size:field:1:0 
0.00:fixed:size:0`
```

When I use this it creates a custom option but without a Title name and no SKU image below.

[image]

When I try this

```
Choose your Size:field:1:0
:0.00:fixed:size:0
```

the use of " : "before the 0.00 then it creates the following

[image]

In this case everything is correct except that its missing the price of "**0.00**"

This is how it should be created as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

use a double `" :: "` before 0.00 as follows.

```
Choose your Size:field:1:0 
::0.00:size:size:0
```